# Spring MVC - Stop redirect in Controller function

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, url

I have a Spring MVC Controller and a PUT mapping that consumes JSON. I receive the JSON and everything just fine, the problem is whenever I fire off the JSON the mapper wants to redirect to the URL, giving me error 500 because the server can't find any template for the URL. How can I stop Spring MVC from trying to redirect to the URL and just receive the JSON?

My relevant Controller code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "admin/users/VMs", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = "application/json")
public void removeVM(@RequestBody ManageVMRequest packet, Authentication authentication) {
    System.out.println(packet.getVm());
    System.out.println(packet.getUser_id());
}
```

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to return `ResponseEntity<Void>`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "admin/users/VMs", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Void> removeVM(@RequestBody ManageVMRequest packet, Authentication authentication) {
   System.out.println(packet.getVm());
   System.out.println(packet.getUser_id());
   return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```